# Is there a limit to data that can be posted to web2py?

Tags: python, post, web2py

I am posting data to an web2py API.  For a short data string, POST succeeds without issue.  A slightly longer data string returns "Response [200]", but the entry does successfully post to the database.

This is for a web2py deployment on www.pythonanywhere.com.  There does not appear to be any meaningful limit for Web2Py, Python, or www.pythonanywhere.com (where web2py is running), especially for the data size lengths that I am using (really tiny).

Here is an example.  'json_data' in data_list successfully posts.  'json_data2' in data_list does not.  'json_data' is only about 200 characters long.  'json_data2' is about 1000.  The length is the only variable that I can find that determines success failure, but I find it hard to believe that length is the issue:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from datetime import datetime

auth=HTTPBasicAuth('LoginID', 'Password')
json_data = '{"batt chrg": {"dat": "-999%", "measurement": "percent", "unit": "electric", "entrytype": "subunitStatus"}, "pv gen": {"dat": "-999 W", "measurement": "level", "unit": "electric", "entrytype": "subunitStatus"}}'
json_data2 = '{"download": {"entrytype": "subunitStatus", "dat": "9 Mbit/s", "measurement": "level", "unit": "comms"}, "batt chrg": {"entrytype": "subunitStatus", "dat": "94.4%", "measurement": "percent", "unit": "electric"}, "pv gen": {"entrytype": "subunitStatus", "dat": "543 W", "measurement": "level", "unit": "electric"}, "living space": {"entrytype": "subunitStatus", "dat": "72 F", "measurement": "level", "unit": "hvac"}, "ping": {"entrytype": "subunitStatus", "dat": "60 ms", "measurement": "level", "unit": "comms"}, "invert load": {"entrytype": "subunitStatus", "dat": "402 W", "measurement": "level", "unit": "electric"}, "humidity": {"entrytype": "subunitStatus", "dat": "45%", "measurement": "level", "unit": "hvac"}, "upload": {"entrytype": "subunitStatus", "dat": "8 Mbit/s", "measurement": "level", "unit": "comms"}}'


unitid = '19700111'
uploaded = 'no'
data = {
    'unitid': unitid,
    'uploaded': uploaded,
    'time_stamp': str(datetime.now()),
    'data_list': json_data2,
    }

rq = requests.post(
"https://XXXXX.pythonanywhere.com/XXX/default/api/packed_data.json",
data=data,
auth=auth,
headers={'Connection':'close'}
)
```

The code on the web2py side is standard:

```
def api():  
    response.view = 'generic.'+request.extension
    def GET(*args,**vars):
        patterns = 'auto'
        parser = db.parse_as_rest(patterns,args,vars)
        if parser.status == 200:
            return dict(content=parser.response)
        else:
            raise HTTP(parser.status,parser.error)
    def POST(table_name,**vars):
        return db[table_name].validate_and_insert(**vars)
    def PUT(table_name,record_id,**vars):
        return db(db[table_name]._id==record_id).update(**vars)
    def DELETE(table_name,record_id):
        return db(db[table_name]._id==record_id).delete()
    return dict(GET=GET, POST=POST, PUT=PUT, DELETE=DELETE)
```

I expect a "Response [200]" and for the entry to post in my packed_data database.  I receive the  "Response [200]", but no entry is recorded.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Your question spends a lot of time explaining what you think the answer might be (namely, a data-limit of web2py), and very little time explaining what the problem is. Could you spend some more time explaining what's actually going wrong? Check out [mcve] for the kind of details we need to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Good comment.  I will try to repost with a better perspective.